# Color picker – indicator / selection marker

Tags: color, touch-screen, indicator

I have a color and brightness picker:

[image]

It has been designed for touch interaction; you can scroll it horizontally. Now here's the thing: **How do I design a good indicator for the currently selected color?**

---

I tried some things, but I don't think they do too well.

[image: first attempt]

[image: second attempt]

---

I'd like it to be...

- simple and clean;
- the selection should be obvious;
- nice looking

The selector doesn't move at all, it's just the inner part of the selector that moves when you scroll through the colors.

---

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a modified version of the first one, perhaps like so:

[image: Modified Slider 1]

What this essentially is is the first one, but with a box above to give an elegant preview of what you are currently pointing at. It will be above the user's fingers, and therefore out of their way.

The reason I chose the first slider is because it has a bar, which is definitely the best way to give an idea of what is being selected, thus making it the most intuitive, and the most elegant.

Some other suggestions I can make is to possibly have the box *under* the `value` slider, because of it's position in relation to the `color` slider will make it crammed to have it over. Although, it is always in your best interest to keep UI consistant, so if you are adding any more than 2 sliders of this type (you have `H` and `V`, you can possibly add `S`) than I highly reccomend you to keep the boxes **above** the bar at all times (or under, based on where you decide to keep it for the first box).

In response to your requirement

> The selector doesn't move at all, it's just the inner part of the selector that moves when you scroll through the colors.

That is reasonable, but for your current problem, I think it is not  a good idea to have the box separate, as it can confuse the user.

Comment: Would you show the box above the selection marker at all times or just while the user is interacting with it?

Comment: Just while the user is interacting with it, it is the expected functionality.

Comment: No problem! Hope it works well for you :)